# CW Location Poller - Doesn't force the GPS to attempt a lock

Tags: android, android-location, commonsware-cwac

I've asked a question about Commonware's location poller before and got it to work before. Its still working but there is a problem.

Yesterday, (after a bit of experimenting and code studying lol) I realized that in order to get location using both options (prefer GPS, but if not available use Network) I had to pass the extra as 'BOTH'.

After doing that however, the LocationPollerService doesn't FORCE the GPS to locate me. Let me describe the issue below.

Suppose I have my GPS on, and another app actively using the GPS and maintaining a lock. Now, if I use the LocationPollerService, it will return me the value from GPS. **However**, when my GPS in on, but isn't locked, LocationPollerService doesn't attempt a lock but merely moves on to Network-based Location which isn't what I need when I have GPS enabled.

I would've added code here but I believe this is question specific to **cwac-locpoll** and the code is already online.

Here's the link:

[Commonware's Location Poller](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll)

My question? How do I force the service to attempt a location fix when GPS is on?

**Update**

Here's where I think it looks for GPS location but doesn't actually attempt one. If you could help, that would be great.

```
@Override protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // Added in enabled check to even check if there is a provider
            // enabled.

            if (provider.equalsIgnoreCase("BOTH"))
            {
                if (!locMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && !locMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Both providers are disabled");
                    // There is no provider so fail with the LKL if possible
                    Intent toBroadcast = new Intent(intentTemplate);
                    toBroadcast.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR, "Location Provider disabled!");
                    toBroadcast.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR_PROVIDER_DISABLED, true);

                    Location lastLoc = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (lastLoc == null)
                        lastLoc = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    toBroadcast.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LASTKNOWN, lastLoc);
                    sendBroadcast(toBroadcast);

                    quit();
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if (!locMgr.isProviderEnabled(provider))
            {
                Log.i(TAG, provider + " is disabled");
                // There is no provider so fail with the LKL if possible
                Intent toBroadcast = new Intent(intentTemplate);
                toBroadcast.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR, "Location Provider disabled!");
                toBroadcast.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR_PROVIDER_DISABLED, true);
                toBroadcast.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LASTKNOWN, locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
                sendBroadcast(toBroadcast);

                quit();
                return;
            }

            onTimeout = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Intent toBroadcast = new Intent(intentTemplate);

                    toBroadcast.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR, "Timeout!");
                    toBroadcast.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR_PROVIDER_DISABLED, false);

                    Location lastLoc = null;
                    if (provider.equalsIgnoreCase("BOTH"))
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Both provider timed out");
                        lastLoc = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (lastLoc == null)
                            lastLoc = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, provider + " timed out");
                        lastLoc = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                    }

                    toBroadcast.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LASTKNOWN, lastLoc);
                    sendBroadcast(toBroadcast);
                    quit();
                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(onTimeout, TIMEOUT);

            try
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Provider: " + provider);
                if (provider.equalsIgnoreCase("BOTH"))
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Adding both providers");
                    locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
                    locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
                }
                else
                {
                    locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, listener);
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                // see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21237
                Log.w(TAG, "Exception requesting updates -- may be emulator issue", e);
                quit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since there is no support for the string `BOTH` in my code, I think you are thinking of somebody else's library.

Comment: @CommonsWare wow :/ It indeed is different. Looking at your code, if a location provider is not found, it sends the last known location. How is this location obtained? Does it use Network Provider on its own?

Also, I'm adding some code so if you can help me..

Comment: "How is this location obtained?" -- by calling `getLastKnownLocation()` for whatever provider you requested. "Does it use Network Provider on its own?" -- no, it uses whatever provider you requested.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you take a look at the above code?

Comment: That is not my code. If you wish to have help from the author of that code, go find its author. Since that's not from the one maintained fork that I know of for `LocationPoller`, I cannot advise you on the source of the code you list above.